# Find all the values of the parameter 'a' for which the given inequality is satisfied for all real values of x.

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Find all the values of the parameter 'a' for which the inequality is satisfied for all real values of x.

$$a\cdot 9^x+4\cdot \left(a-1\right)\cdot 3^x+\left(a-1\right)>0$$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$a\cdot \left(9^x+4\cdot 3^x+1\right)-(4\cdot 3^x+1)>0$$

$$a\cdot \left(9^x+4\cdot 3^x+1\right)>4\cdot 3^x+1$$

$$a>\frac{4\cdot 3^x+1}{9^x+4\cdot 3^x+1}$$

Now if a is greater than the maximum value of $\frac{4\cdot 3^x+1}{9^x+4\cdot 3^x+1}$, then inequality will be true for all x.

So if we can find the range of $\frac{4\cdot 3^x+1}{9^x+4\cdot 3^x+1}$, then we can say a should be greater than the maximum value in the range.

Let's assume y=$\frac{4\cdot 3^x+1}{9^x+4\cdot 3^x+1}$ and substitute $3^x$ with $t$.

$$y=\frac{4t+1}{t^2+4t+1}$$

$$yt^2+4ty+y=4t+1$$

$$yt^2+4t(y-1)+y-1=0$$

We want to have real values of t satisfying the equation, so $D>=0$

$$16(y-1)^2-4*y*\left(y-1\right)>=0$$

$$4(y-1)(4y-4-y)>=0$$

$$4(y-1)(3y-4)>=0$$

$$y\in \left(-\infty,1 \right] \cup \left[\frac{4}{3},\infty\right)$$

So I am getting maximum value tending to $\infty$ for y=$\frac{4\cdot 3^x+1}{9^x+4\cdot 3^x+1}$

I am not able to understand where am I making mistake.

Official answer is $a\in \left[1,\infty\right) $

Comment: $$(3^x)^2 \ne 9^x$$

Comment: who said ?, think again

Comment: @Legorhin: Surely $(3^x)^2 = 3^{2x} = (3^2)^x = 9^x$?

Comment: I haven't checked but when you replace $3^x$ by $t$, there is an assumption that $t>0$.

Comment: ok i'm wrong, whoops

Answer (score 3):

Prove that $$\frac{4\cdot3^x+1}{9^x+4\cdot3^x+1}<1$$ for any real $x$.

Now, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\frac{4\cdot3^x+1}{9^x+4\cdot3^x+1}=1,$$ which gives $$\sup\frac{4\cdot3^x+1}{9^x+4\cdot3^x+1}=1$$ and the answer $a\geq1.$

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way :-):

Let $t = 3^x$, noting that we need $t>0$. The equation becomes
$at^2+4(a-1)t +(a-1) > 0$ for all $t>0$.

First note that if the above is true for all $t >0$ then we must have (taking
the limit as $t \downarrow 0$) that $(a-1) \ge 0$ (note $\ge$ not $>$).

In
particular, $a \ge 1$ must hold.

The $\min$ of the left hand side (over **all** $t$) can be found using:
$2at + 4(a-1) = 0$, or $t^* = -2 {a-1\over a}$.

Since $t^* \le 0$, we see (because it is a quadratic) that the 
left hand side is an increasing function of $t$ for $t \ge 0$ and the 
value at $t=0$ is $a-1$.

In particular, if $t >0$ we have $at^2+4(a-1)t +(a-1) > a-1\ge 0$.

Comment: I think my approach is very mature and easy to understand as it decomposed the question into cases and in the last we did union of all cases.

Comment: Just giving an immature alternative :-).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the point where I did mistake, thanks to @copper.hat

It is important to note that when substituting $3^x$ with $t$, it means t will also be greater than $0$.

So we have to find the condition where at least one root is positive, so there can be multiple cases to it.

Case 1: When both the roots are positive, it means product of roots should be positive and sum of roots should be positive, so from the equation $yt^2+4t(y-1)+y-1=0$ , we can say $\frac{y-1}{y}>0$ and $\frac{-4\left(y-1\right)}{y}>0$, so $y\in \phi$.

Case 2: When one root is positive and other root is negative, it means product of roots should be negative, so from the equation $yt^2+4t(y-1)+y-1=0$, we can say $\frac{y-1}{y}<0$, so $y\in (0,1)$

Case 3: When one root is zero and other root is positive, it means product of roots should be zero and sum of roots should be positive, $\frac{y-1}{y}=0$ and $\frac{-4\left(y-1\right)}{y}>0$, so $y=1$ and $y\in \left(0,1\right)$, so $y\in \phi$

Taking union of all conditions in case $1,2,3$ , we get $y\in (0,1)$, so maximum value is tending to $1$ but not $1$. Hence $a \in \left[1,\infty\right)$